# Error when activating the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" site collection feature inside my online team site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, publishing-site

i am working on an office 365 project. and i have created a new team site collection. but when i tried to activate the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" site collection feature , i got the following error, after waiting for a couple of minutes:-

[image]

now i checked if the feature has been activated or not, and i can see that it is activated as follow:-

[image]

also inside my site collection, i have noted that new libraries have been created, where these libraries are created as part of activating the publishing site collection feature. but now i am not sure what does the above error indicate? should i remove the site collection, and create a new one? as i do not want to start working on my new site collection while it have hidden errors or problems, since i got the above error while trying to activate the publishing feature?

Answer (score 2):

If your site is still empty, personally I'd recreate it after such an error, just to feel 100% safe.

It's hard to tell if any Feature Activation steps were missed / incomplete due to the error you got. Since SharePoint tells you the Feature is "Active" now everything should be OK. The error might have happened while reloading the Features page after pressing pressing the "Activate" button while everything else went just fine.

Comment: the problem i can not be sure if the site collection is not corrupted .. now since this is  a new site collection, so i delete it, recreate another site collection,, try to activate the feature but i got the same error..so i am not sure what i can do ?

Comment: If the problem persists and occurs everytime you try to activate Publishing Features I recommend submitting a service request through the Office 365 Admin Portal.

Comment: can you mention from where i can submit a service request ticket? and it is for free?

Comment: In the O365 admin center under "Support" you can create a new service request which indeed is free.

Answer (score 1):

We had faced the same issue multiple times and this was the check list that we used:

1) Deactivate and Reactivate this feature.

2) If there was error in the first step, recreate the site collection and then attempt to activate the feature again.

3) If the error still persists, then open a ticket with Microsoft support. It usually means, there is something wrong with the tenant

Comment: i deleted the site collection and recreate it again.. but still i will face the same error. although i have other site collections were i was able to activate this feature on last week... so should i open a ticket with MS ? or there are other appraochies i can follow other than recreating the site collection which did not work...

Comment: now i tried deactivate the feature and then reactivate it again where it worked.i had the feature activated without any problem.. but if i create a new site collection then i will not be able to activate it from the first time... so is this fine??

Comment: Not fine. Would be best to open a ticket.

Comment: where i can open the ticket?

Comment: now i am not sure what is going on.. i use to name the site collection as Home. now i remove the current site collection, then i create a new site collection with a new name "CustomerHomeSite" and i can activate the feature.. but i have noted that it takes around 5 minute to get it activated...so could using the name home for the site collection name and url (sites/home) be the problem ???

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenkumar/2013/07/17/how-to-create-service-requests-to-contact-office-365-support/ , check this link on how to do it. Its free. Should have nothing to do with name. Time taken to activate feature is fine. Best to get it checked out.

Comment: now after many create/delete/recreate site collection i was able to create the site collection named Home and got the publishing features activated from the first time... so i should be ok ...

Answer (score 0):

Is this a modern Communications Site? If so, SharePoint Server Publishing cannot be activated, which also means cannot create Enterprise Search subsite which requires this functionality. Cannot find a hack or workaround. Check back in 2030, might be resolved by then...